# a problem with multiprocesssing in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to learn multiprocessing in python and I have written a very simple code. But it does not print anything for me.
The code is:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def fun(lang):
    print(lang)

if __name__=='__main__':
    langs = ['C', 'python', 'Java', 'PHP']
    processes = []
    for l in langs:
        proc = Process(target=fun, args=(l,))
        processes.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Can you help me to figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Prints fine for me... How are you running this?

Comment: Depending on the OS and Popen settings you might not see the print since every process has its own stdout where the print goes to.

Comment: @ Tomerikoo I run it in Jupiter in a normal way.

Comment: @ Klaus D. what should I do to see the print now? where can I change the settings?

Comment: Please check whether you can see the output of a `print` statement that you put into the main (parent) process - maybe try one at the start and also one at the end. This will determine whether the problem relates to the multiprocessing or there is some other reason why you cannot see the print output. At least on Linux, the child will inherit the same file descriptors as in the parent, so the stdout from all of them will end up in the same place (via separate output buffers, but these buffers will be flushed prior to termination when you do the `join`).

Comment: can you mention jupyter and python versions and the running os?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine under regular Python but if you run it under IPython (notebooks) it won't print anything.
Try putting your code in a .py file and run it with Python from console